# Access all the attributes of one-to-one linked model if not found in current model

Tags: python, django

I have a model that is linked to another as `OneToOneField`. For example:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    #other fields ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to get the attribute with dot notation if it exists in Profile or User. I did the following:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ....

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if self.user:
            return self.user.name 
        else:
            raise AttributeError
        return super().__getattr__(self,name)
```

For example, if `Profile` does not have `email` field, I would like to get it as `profile.email` (`profile` is a `Profile` instance) if it exists in `User`.

However I get error as below.

```
    if self.user:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

How can I achieve this behavior - get the attribute from current instance, if not available, and if the one-to-one field is not none, lookup there?

Comment: I don't understand what behavior you're trying to achieve. Why does `Profile` model have a `profile` attribute? Do you mean `return getattr(self.profile, name)`?

Comment: @miyamoto I have corrected. I actually meant `self.user`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for this method. you know what model has which attribute so why you should call a method blindly? this confuses other co-developers and you should not do this. in worst-case, I would make a property:

```
@property
def get_name(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'name'):
        return self.name
    return self.user.first_name # there is no name field in django user model
```

Comment: The example I gave is just for demonstration. I would not use that approach for standard model as `Use`. But I have a custom Model and there are several attributes (property, fields, methods), and I want to access all of them.

Comment: @DurgaDatta what you mean by "all of them". you have access to all of them always. where is the core problem that lead you to this question?

Comment: I do not want to write property or individual accesser  for each of them.

Comment: @DurgaDatta I dont understand why you need individual accessor or property? why not just access them as usual?

Comment: I will have to check for None in several places. I can't do profile.user.email if the user field of Profile is None. Additionally I cant user them in django admin, for example, unless I write property.

Comment: @DurgaDatta then make sure user field is not None ;) you should redesign your models if you think the logic is not fluent. wrapping each field because they are none is not optimal way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116643/discussion-between-durgadatta-and-doniyor).

Answer (score 1):

Something like?

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if hasattr(self, name):
         return getattr(self, name)
    elif hasattr(self, "user") and hasattr(self.user, name):
         return getattr(self.user, name)
    else:
         raise AttributeError
```